# Div dynamically added by dynarch calendar not accessible by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I need to access the div created by the dynarch calendar with jQuery `.each()`. However that is not possible when also using this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert(jQuery(".calendar").val());
  },2000);
});
```

The calendar is setup with this:

```
var calendarSetupObject2 = {
  inputField  : "options_15_date",
  ifFormat    : "%d.%m.%Y",
  showsTime   : "false",
  button      : "options_15_date_trig2",
  align       : "Bl",
  singleClick : true,
}
calendarSetupObject2.range = [2016, 2016]

Calendar.setup(calendarSetupObject2);
```

The div appears in the DOM inspector of Firefox.

How do I access it?

Comment: would need some more information or code sample to be able to answer this question.

Comment: There is a high chance that your selector is generated by the calendar lib you're using which means that you need to use a callback fn after your calendar script is initialized. Look back the calendar API and seach for the callbacks. Then call your $(...).val() fn

Comment: I have added a link to the code of the calendar and of the setup.

Comment: I think the div is added with this Calendar.createElement = function(type, parent) {
    var el = null;
    if (document.createElementNS) {
        // use the XHTML namespace; IE won't normally get here unless
        // _they_ "fix" the DOM2 implementation.
        el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", type);
    } else {
        el = document.createElement(type);
    }
    if (typeof parent != "undefined") {
        parent.appendChild(el);
    }
    return el;
};

How to access the div that was added with that?